# How to have two instances of a class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, variables

I have created a class and want to create two separate instances of this class. I've been able to achieve this in web applications, but I'm attempting to do this in a windows form and for some reason when I create the second instance of the class it has the variable data from the first instance.

I've tried to create the two instances as global variables as I want them to be accessed by separate sub routines. The two instances are declared as such:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim oTree1_Animation As New clsAnimation()
    Dim oTree2_Animation As New clsAnimation()
```

I then attempt to populate the instance in a sub routine which fires on a MouseDown event:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Dim oFrame As New clsFrame(2, {0, -32}, {0, 0})
    Dim timTimer As New Timer()
    oTree1_Animation.Initialise(2, 100, oFrame, PictureBox1, timTimer)
    oTree1_Animation.AnimationStart()
End Sub
```

The second is then populated in a similar fashion:

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown
    Dim oFrame As New clsFrame(2, {0, -32}, {0, 0})
    Dim timTimer As New Timer()
    oTree2_Animation.Initialise(2, 100, oFrame, PictureBox2, timTimer)
    oTree2_Animation.AnimationStart()
End Sub
```

The class looks like this:

```
Public Class clsAnimation
    Public Event Tick As EventHandler

    Public Shared FrameCount As Integer
    Public Shared FrameInterval As Integer
    Public Shared CurrentFrame As Integer = 0
    Public Shared FrameSet As clsFrame
    Public Shared Image As PictureBox
    Public Shared WithEvents Timer As Timer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates an empty instance of the Animation class
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the Animation class and preloads it with variables
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="iFrameCount">Number of frames in this animation as Integer</param>
    ''' <param name="iFrameInterval">Frame transition speed (milliseconds) as Integer</param>
    ''' <param name="clsFrameSet">Frame information as clsFrame</param>
    ''' <param name="imgImage">The picturebox that we're animating as PictureBox</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub Initialise(ByVal iFrameCount As Integer, ByVal iFrameInterval As Integer, ByVal clsFrameSet As clsFrame, ByRef imgImage As PictureBox, ByRef timTimer As Timer)
        FrameCount = iFrameCount
        FrameInterval = iFrameInterval
        FrameSet = clsFrameSet
        Image = imgImage
        Timer = timTimer

        Timer.Interval = FrameInterval
    End Sub
```

However, both oTree1_Animation and oTree2_Animation share the same variables. I don't know if I'm missing something small or if I'm just trying to use classes in an impossible way, any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove `Shared` from all your class variables. `Shared` means that the values are shared between all instances of this class.

This is normally referred to as "static" (but for some reason VB.NET uses a different terminology).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for Microsoft explanation (thanks benjineer).

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something that I was missing. However, I had set them to shared because I wanted a sub-routine in the class to be able to access those variables, how would I go about doing that?

EDIT: I stopped the sub-routines being shared and everything appears to be working as I had expected now.. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Microsoft's explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Methods of the class can access all instance variables unless they are themselves shared.